# How to extract value from a formatted price?

Tags: java, regex

I would like a regex in java that extracts the value from a price. For example, $40,250.99
I would like the expression to output 40250.99. The key thing is that it has to be done only with regular expressions. I cannot do any String concatenation or other String related manipulations. I have tried the following but "," messes up everything. Basically $503.34 would yield 503.34 but $40,250.99 yields 40

```
String extractionPattern = "[\\$](\\d+(?:\\.\\d{1,2})?)";
String val = "    Executive billings @ $40,250.99 Starting 2013-01-05 with bi weekly";
Pattern  p = Pattern.compile(extractionPattern);
Matcher m = p.matcher(val);
if (m.find())
     System.out.println("Found a match:" + m.group(1));
```

Comment: Can you use `replace` or `replaceAll` methods? Just asking because you said `I cannot do any String concatenation` and despite that you are using it in `"Found a match:" + m.group(1)`. If not then your problem probably can't be solved with regex because it can't return in one match few separate substrings so you wont be able to get rid of commas.

Comment: Just to make sure: is it a typo in your example or you really want to remove comma from `$40,250.99` and make it `40250.99`? In case you don't have to remove it try this `"\\$(\\d+(?:,\\d+)*(?:\\.\\d{1,2})?)"` regex.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably better ways to do this and I'll be the first to admit that my regex is pretty basic...

```
String regExp = "\\$[0-9,\\.]+";
String value = "Executive billings @ $40,250.99 Starting 2013-01-05 with bi weekly";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regExp);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(value);

// This should result in a list with 1 element of "$40,250.99"
List<String> lstMatches = new ArrayList<String>(5);
while (matcher.find()) {
    lstMatches.add(matcher.group());
}

for (String match : lstMatches) {
    // Strip off the unrqeuired elements...
    match = match.replaceAll("\\$", "");
    match = match.replaceAll(",", "");
    System.out.println(Double.parseDouble(match));
}
```

You may even be able to use `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().parse(match)` to parse the result back to a `double`, but this would assume that the input matches the local requirements...

Comment: Thank you for your replies, however I cannot do any replaceAll or any other string manipulation. This is used for a third party system that takes a regular expression as an argument in one of its commands and extracts values. I wish I had access to Java but I don't. Therefore, I need a single regular expression that extracts the value. Thank you all for your help.